# .net mvc tiered application with observer vs msmq vs web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, msmq, observer-pattern

Background: MVC app has 100+transactions/second and needs detailed real time reporting.

Issue: Reporting against transactional database means convoluted reporting logic + slow reporting load times.  Big reports can negatively impact transactional processes. Pulling data into de-normalized cubes at regular intervals violates real time reporting constraints

Solution: have state changes persist to transactional database as well as the cube at the same time, de-normalizing the data as it gets persisted in the cube (1-2 minute latency is ok)

Dilemma: each layer, web, app, transactional database, and cube are horizontally scaled and exist on different farms in different geographical locations.

Possible Resolutions:
MSMQ with multicast - app server sends messages on entity state change, and transactional db and cube service receives message and persist. Pros: mature solution, cons: Requires a lot of hardware and/or licensing to ensure high availability - translation: expensive.

Observer pattern - use .net WCF (ugh..) to have App server invoke change events which the database servers subscribe to (observe). Pros: no extra hardware, cons: WCF.

REST web services - use a .net webclient to post to the transactional db and the cube instead of sending messages or invoking events. Pros: uber simple to implement, cons: need IIS installed somewhere on the db sides for the app server to post to.

Question 1: are my assumptions about the possible resolutions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research, CQRS fits well as a solution.
As far as communication between all the moving parts, I had to read up a lot on enterprise service bus (ESB)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus. In the .net world, nservicebus seems to be popular, but is not free, and mass transit is free, but I'm having trouble building and running the samples. T.T

A good general overview of messaging vs web services by one of they guys behind mass transit: http://blip.tv/ineta-live/event-driven-architecture-by-chris-patterson-north-dallas-net-ug-on-02-03-2010-3193457

The ESB uses MSMQ to implement the observer pattern. Throw in a little web services a la [cqrs eventstore dispatching to via web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237025/cqrs-eventstore-dispatching-to-via-web-service) then that means all the resolutions are basically used, but I would leverage open source components.