# cqrs eventstore dispatching to via web service

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs

Other than latency, is there a significant disadvantage to looping through a list of web services to post the event?

```
Dispatcher(event) {
    var services = getServices();
    for each service in services {
        callService(service, event);
    }
}
```

Edit:
As opposed to what? – Peter Ritchie

- Using web services as opposed to MSMQ or nServiceBus.

Other questions – Ruben Bartelink

- Using joliver's eventstore.
- A webservice would be a webapi restfull service (internally) or third party service that is "subscribed" to the event.
- Looping through the web services because each web service is an address that needs dispatching.
- No c# code yet because I haven't gotten to that point, yet.
- I'm still evaluating technologies across the project, had a question, decided to put it out here on stack overflow to see what everyone might be doing.

Supplemental info from my research yesterday:
In terms of choosing a communication method, its useful to know about enterprise service bus (ESB)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus. In the .net world, nservicebus seems to be popular, but is not free, and mass transit is free, but I'm having trouble building and running the samples. T.T

A good general overview of messaging vs web services by one of they guys behind mass transit: http://blip.tv/ineta-live/event-driven-architecture-by-chris-patterson-north-dallas-net-ug-on-02-03-2010-3193457

Comment: Using what event store/methodology. What is your definition of a web service. Why are you looping. Do they all need it. What else have you tried. Why not convert it to real C#. Are you aware that the typical way people rig things is to have the dispatching of events be async. Do you intend to keep it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing events by calling various web services directly from your user facing application layer may prove troublesome if:

1. The remote service is not available,
2. the remote service is broken and returns unexpected error codes,
3. the remote service is slooooow and your users are no big fans of waiting around,
4. etc.

By publishing the events via a queue to some working application, resposible for invoking the various web serivces, your front end application need not fail due to any of the above.

Comment: So use something like MSMQ, nServiceBus, Mass Transit, etc.. to stick the events somewhere (DB, filesystem, etc..) and have a background app (chron job, windows service, etc..) pull from the somewhere and initiate the web services?

Comment: @ton.yeung Your Dispatcher puts stuff onto a queue. Your Projections then run any number of processors (e.g. Denormalizers) in response to the messages. While it is valid that the duties of one such processor is to **push** the data into a webservice, you're better off reorienting to have anything that needs stuff pull it from a queue or topic / pub-sub thing.

Comment: @ton.yeung: Excatly. MSMQ or RabbitMQ would both serve fine as durable queues, both capable of storing messages without any auxiliary databases. NServiceBus, Mass Transit and Rebus are frameworks that makes it easy for you to send and recieve messages from these queues.

Comment: @RubenBartelink: Agreed. If the web services are outside of OPs control (partners, online APIs, etc), pushing might be the only way to go though.

Comment: at-Jørn @ton.yeung BTW I +1'd and fully agree with Jørn'd answer - managing the Dispatching via a queue allows you to deal with failure and other inconsistencies in the push process you're outlining. Remember, once the event is in the Event Store, it has happened -- all that's left is for the world to sync up with the new reality. Having said that, read http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/22/busting-some-cqrs-myths/ and http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/23/cqrs-and-user-experience/ - its important to keep an open mind and meet your customer requirements (cited pages down now;sry)